# how to get windows logged in user details using javascript or angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hi i am developing one intranet app for this i have a functionality like i need get ther username and password of whom are logged in that particular system
i got following snippet for ie

```
var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject("WScript.network");
document.write(objUserInfo.ComputerName+"<br>"); 
document.write(objUserInfo.UserDomain+"<br>"); 
document.write(objUserInfo.UserName+"<br>");  
var uname =  objUserInfo.UserName;
alert(uname);
```

but it is not working any other browser
can acny one help me regarding this 
note:i am okay if there is any alternate solution for this

Comment: For activex internet explorer is mandatory. its the only browser that supports it. Also set your intra net site to the trusted zone.

Comment: thank you michael but is there any way to achieve this in firefox and chrome browsers

Comment: Not natively. You would have to install plugins that do it for you. Chances are you need to write those yourself. Possibly even have to write it in the source